# Can I search a cell for specific text using IFS formula, and return text to current cell?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I was able to do this with a single IF formula, but cannot exactly figure out how to do it with IFS to search the same cell for different strings of text.

Here is the formula I am using for the single IF statement:

```
=IF(SEARCH("silver",B5),"silver","N/A")
```

It is searching cell B5 for the term "silver" and then if found it returns "silver". If not it returns N/A. I would like to be able to search cell B5 for different terms ("black","red","blue") using the IFS formula.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the Excel rows]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can continue to nest `IF` statements. So swap your "N/A" for another `IF` statement and so on. If you have many values to search for this gets quit tedious though

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX({"Silver","Black","Red","Blue"},AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($1:$4)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"Silver","Black","Red","Blue"},B2))),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, using LOOKUP+SEARCH function

In `M2`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,-SEARCH({"silver","black","red","blue"},B2),{"Silver","Black","Red","Blue"}),"")
```

[image]